# GPG Password Agent and SSH Key Agent

Tags: 14.04, ssh, password, gnupg

Yesterday I wanted to add an app to the startup menu, and I noticed that there are two instances that weren't there before: GPG Password Agent and SSH Key Agent.

I didn't install those, and I read it has something to do with passwords. Is that part of the Ubuntu system, that installed with some update and is it safe to be there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Those are automatically added when you install OpenSSH server (sshd).  It allows you to use keys instead of passwords with ssh, making it more secure.  I believe the keyring is what allows you to have the server remember the key so that you don't have to constantly keep reentering it every time you do a command such as `scp`, which is very convenient if you are copying a number of files (or other ssh commands).